# spring mvc: logging exception without overriding spring's default handler

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, exception

i want to log all server side errors. so i added

```
@ControllerAdvice
public class MyHandler {

   @ExceptionHandler(Throwable.class)
   ResponseEntity handle(HttpServletRequest req, Throwable t) {
     // if t is clientError return 400
     // else log and return 500
   }    
}
```

but now i have to manually list all default spring's 4xx errors like e.g. `HttpMediaTypeNotSupportedException`. what can i do to first let spring's default handler handles all errors it can, and only then run my `MyHandler`?

or maybe there is some other way of intercepting unhandled errors in spring?

Comment: you can use aspects, there is **@AfterThrowing** annotation.

Comment: how does it solve my problem? i still don't know how can i make spring handles its exceptions first, before my own code will handle all other kinds of errors

Comment: What I would like to see is a way to log all the exceptions that Spring maps to a 4xx status as INFO or DEBUG while logging all exceptions Spring maps to 5xx as ERROR.    Developers will play around with the REST API and generate all kinds of 4xx errors while they're figuring things out.  These kinds of errors can be ignored mostly.   But 5xx errors represent a likely bug in our code and I really want to know about those!   We have a default {{@ExceptionHandler}} in an {{@ControllerAdivce}}, also.   So we're logging everything as ERROR.  Not a great solution.